Why aren't integer64 values saved properly in a RDS file?
I'm reading a .dat file containing very large integer values and then I save it in a RDS file. Then, when I read this new file, the integer values have changed.
data.table::freadr loads the values as class bit64::integer64 whereas readRDS loads them as class integer (limited to 2^31).
My guess is saveRDS (or readRDS?) coerces the integer64 class into the integer class.
There's an additional twist: if I load the RDS file in the same session, the values are just fine. But if I reopen another R session and then load the file, then they have changed.
My questions are:

is it a bug or normal behavior? I don't see anything in the documentation.
Why is it different when I read the RDS straight after saving it or when I load it in another R session? Is there some kind of cache?

Reprex
I import ATUS-CPS data from the US BLS, which comes in a .dat format (https://www.bls.gov/tus/datafiles/atuscps-0321.zip, 96.1Mb).
library(data.table)
data <- data.table::fread("atuscps_0321.dat")
saveRDS(data[, "TUCASEID"], file="data.RDS")

and then in another R session
data <- readRDS("data.RDS")

Upon reopening, the value 20030100013007 has become 9.896184e-311

Have you loaded data.table in the new session?

You may be hitting the limits of R's own serialization to disk for types that are not native to R: there is no SEXP for integer64, rather it is a very clever (and generally) robust reinterpreation of double as int64_t payload. So besides ensuring you do library(data.table) to interpret the saved object correctly, you could also try different serialization packages such as qs, qs2 or fst may help?

Asking us to load a 96Mb file to show the effect on a single value does not create a minimal reproducible example.

As an alternative to data.table,  you could read the source file as character strings and then use my package bigBits to convert to values of class bigz via the gmp package.  Depends a bit (pun intended) as to what you need or want to do with said integers.

As hinted by @iroha in the comment, the issue is that your new session does not have data.table loaded.
Demo (for ease of use in the same session, you can also persist the filename)
> suppressMessages({library(bit64); library(data.table)})
> D <- data.table(ind=as.integer64(1:3), val=letters[1:3])
> D
     ind    val
   <i64> <char>
1:     1      a
2:     2      b
3:     3      c
> tf <- tempfile(fileext=".rds")
> saveRDS(D, file=tf)
> 
> rm(D)
> D <- readRDS(tf)
> D
     ind    val
   <i64> <char>
1:     1      a
2:     2      b
3:     3      c
> 
> tf2 <- tempfile(fileext=".rds")
> saveRDS(D[, "ind"], file=tf2)
> readRDS(tf2)
     ind
   <i64>
1:     1
2:     2
3:     3
> 


I'd add a demo with data.table not loaded.

Yes. Reproducible examples are always welcome, and as @Limey hinted, we value minimally complete verifiable examples (aka MRE / MCVE).

Sorry, I didn't get your response. I meant that your answer could be improved showing output without data.table package loaded when integer64 class is not available.

The issue is that in your new session the namespace of package bit64 (where class "integer64" is defined) is not loaded, and therefore you have no access to S3 methods for class "integer64". To obtain access, you can load the namespace directly:
loadNamespace("bit64")

or you can cause the namespace to be loaded by calling any of its methods explicitly, e.g.
bit64::as.integer64(data)

(But loading or attaching package data.table will not be sufficient.)
